# Connect Stata with Amazon Web Service S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, stata

I'm wondering if there is a way to load data sets I have on my AWS - S3 account into Stata directly. I found that in R there is the `AWS.tools` package, but I have not found something similar for Stata.

Is there an .ado or something I can use?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Sorry! Currently working on Mac OSX - Maverick

Comment: I'm not familiar with AWS, but could `webuse set` and `webuse` be of any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the AWS command line interface and `shell` out from Stata to use it to transfer files to and from Amazon S3. Not very convenient, but workable.

The alternative is to [run R from within Stata](http://statlore.wordpress.com/2013/01/21/how-to-call-r-from-stata/), which seems clunkier.